# Simplest way to delete a "composite" word?

Tags: cursor-motions, normal-mode

Apologies if "composite" is not the technical term. I mean the following:

```
Hi, I-am-a-composite-word and we are not
```

I would like to delete only the composite word. In command mode, if I move the cursor to `I`, then repeating `dw` a few times, or better typing `dw` once, followed by a few `.` presses, will do the trick. However, for various reasons I find myself doing this quite often during the day, thus I was wondering if there's any simpler way.

PS I would **NOT** consider the command `d9w` to be a simpler way. Counting a long sequence of words and dashes is not my idea of "simpler".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you are calling a composite word is actually a WORD (by opposition to a word). Reading [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word) and [`:h WORD`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD) should be helpful:

```
                            *word*
A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, <EOL>).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.
                            *WORD*
A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
```

What you are looking for here is `dW` when you are on the `I` or `diW` when you are anywhere in the word.

Maybe in the future you will also need to read [`:h 'iskeyword'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27).

Comment: thanks for the answer: it works. Apropos of the definition: `A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white space`. `Separated with white space` means that the WORD is separated by other words or WORDS with white space, right?

Comment: @DeltaIV Yup `in-this-sentence there are four"WORDs` the 4 WORDs are `in-this-sentence`, `there`, `are` and `four"WORDs`. It's easy to see when you use `w` and `W` or `b` and `B` motions for example. Note that a whitespace can be a "regular" space or a tab character.

Comment: This answer would be more immediately useful if it started with "What you are looking for here is dW .." rather than forcing the reader to wade through to the middle paragraph to find the solution.

Answer (score 11):

Another more general solution is to delete up to the whitespace character using `dt`  (with a space after the `t`), which means "delete to [character]. This often is useful for things like `dt:` and similar as well.

Comment: what does `dt: ` do?

Comment: When I posted the same answer, I learned that you can use `<code>dt </code>` to include a space on the end.

Comment: @DeltaIV Actually what you really need is to read [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt) and to use `vimtutor`, that will greatly help you to get the basics of Vim

Comment: @statox I used to be skilled at VIM...10 years ago :-) `vimtutor` sounds very interesting. I'm not sure it's installed on the remote server (it looks like not even the `man` utility is installed). However, I'll check: if it's automatically installed together with the `vim` package, then chances are high that I will be able to use it.

Comment: @BurnsBA Thank you, that's really useful for this site. Btw. you can edit posts from others and even get +2 reputation if your edit makes it through some peer review process. But this way, I learned something new as well :-).

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the `f` (find) and `t` (to) commands. I'd probably just `dt`  or `df`  (note the space at the end).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using `dw` and the like, and also want to let it work with double-clicking a word, you can add

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

to your `.vimrc`, which adds `-` as a word character.

Example:

Double-clicking any character in `ab-cd` visually highlights `ab-cd`.

Comment: I'm fine with switching to `dW`, but your solution is also pretty cool because it affects visual mode too, I guess. I mean, by modifying the `iskeyword`, double-clicking and then pressing `d` I should be able to delete `ab-cd`. Right?

Comment: Or maybe I should switch to visual mode with `v`, rather than double-clicking. Right?

Comment: @DeltaIV by modifying iskeyword, you can use any method with word objects (including iw or aw, significantly simpler than using a mouse or visual mode)